# UserWarning: Discrepancy between trainable weights and collected trainable weights error

Tags: python, deep-learning, keras

Hi I'm training VGG16 network for my own dataset. Following has given the code I used.

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from scipy.misc import imread
#get_ipython().magic('matplotlib inline')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import keras
from keras.layers import Dense
import pandas as pd

from keras.applications.vgg16 import VGG16
from keras.preprocessing import image
from keras.applications.vgg16 import preprocess_input
import numpy as np
from keras.applications.vgg16 import decode_predictions
from keras.utils.np_utils import to_categorical

from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.optimizers import SGD
from keras.layers import Input, Dense, Convolution2D, MaxPooling2D, AveragePooling2D, ZeroPadding2D, Dropout, Flatten, merge, Reshape, Activation
import os
from sklearn.metrics import log_loss
import cv2
from keras.models import Model
from sklearn import cross_validation
from imagenet_utils import preprocess_input
from imagenet_utils import preprocess_input,decode_predictions
import tensorflow as tf
from keras.backend.tensorflow_backend import set_session
from skimage import measure, morphology
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.art3d import Poly3DCollection
from os import walk
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
from sklearn.metrics import precision_score
from sklearn.metrics import recall_score
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix

os.environ['CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES'] = '-1'
def load_images():



def train_test_separation():


    df = pd.read_csv('C:/CT_SCAN_IMAGE_SET/resnet_50/dbs2017/data/stage1_labels.csv')
    print(df.head())

    #print (filenames,' ',pathname,' ',BASE_PATH )
    #images=load_images()
    labeling = df['cancer'].as_matrix()

    names=['Not_Cancer','Cancer']

    Y_category=keras.utils.to_categorical(labeling, num_classes=2)
    x = np.array([np.mean(np.load('E:/224x224/%s.npy' % str(id)), axis=0) for id in df['id'].tolist()])

    print ('.......................................',Y_category.shape)

    img_rows, img_cols = 224, 224 # Resolution of inputs
    channel = 3
    num_classes = 2
    batch_size = 50
    nb_epoch = 1

    # Load Cifar10 data. Please implement your own load_data() module for your own dataset
    X_train, Y_train, X_valid, Y_valid = cross_validation.train_test_split(x, Y_category, random_state=42, test_size=0.20)

    print (X_train.shape) #(1107, 3, 224, 224)
    print (Y_train.shape) #(277, 3, 224, 224)
    print (X_valid.shape) #(1107, 2)
    print (Y_valid.shape) #(277, 2)

    X_train = X_train.transpose(0,2,3,1)
    Y_train = Y_train.transpose(0,2,3,1)
    print (X_train.shape) # (1107, 224, 224, 3)
    # Load our model


    # Load our model
    model = vgg16_model(img_rows, img_cols, channel, num_classes)
    print ('.........................................',Y_valid.shape) #(277, 2)
    model.summary()
    # Start Fine-tuning and training

    #config = tf.ConfigProto(log_device_placement=False, allow_soft_placement=True)
    #config.gpu_options.allow_growth=True
    #config.gpu_options.per_process_gpu_memory_fraction = 0.95
    #set_session(tf.Session(config=config))


    hist=model.fit(X_train, X_valid,batch_size=batch_size,epochs=nb_epoch,shuffle=True,verbose=1,validation_data=(Y_train, Y_valid))

    #validation_data: tuple (x_val, y_val) or tuple (x_val, y_val, val_sample_weights) on which to evaluate the loss and any model
    #metrics at the end of each epoch. The model will not be trained on this data. This will override validation_split

    (loss,accuracy)=model.evaluate(Y_train,Y_valid,batch_size=batch_size,verbose=1)

    print ("[INFO] loss={:.4f},accuracy: {:.4f}%".format(loss,accuracy*100))

    df = pd.read_csv('C:/CT_SCAN_IMAGE_SET/resnet_50/dbs2017/data/stage1_sample_submission.csv')
    df2 = pd.read_csv('C:/CT_SCAN_IMAGE_SET/resnet_50/dbs2017/data/stage1_solution.csv')
    x = np.array([np.mean(np.load('E:/224x224/%s.npy' % str(id)), axis=0) for id in df['id'].tolist()])

    x = x.transpose(0,2,3,1)
    # Make predictions
    pred = model.predict(x, batch_size=batch_size, verbose=1) #predict(self, x, batch_size=None, verbose=0, steps=None)

    print (pred)


    # Cross-entropy loss score
    score = log_loss(x, predictions_valid)


def vgg16_model(img_rows, img_cols, channel=1, num_classes=None):
    print ('aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa')

    image_input=Input(shape=(224,224,3))

    model = VGG16(weights='imagenet', include_top=True, input_tensor=image_input)
    print ('bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb')
    model.summary()

    last_layer=model.get_layer('fc2').output # last layer which will be 4096

    # Will add one layer over it.
    out=Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax',name='output')(last_layer)

    custom_vgg_model=Model(image_input,out) #Creating the custom model using the Keras, Modelfunction.

    custom_vgg_model.summary()

    #Now you can train the model. Before that you need to compile it.

    custom_vgg_model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',optimizer='adadelta',metrics=['accuracy'])


    #We do not need to train the etire network. Instead we need to train the last layer.
    #All the layers except thelast layer will be freezed

    for layer in custom_vgg_model.layers[:-1]:
        layer.trainable=False

    custom_vgg_model.layers[3].trainable


    return custom_vgg_model




if __name__ == '__main__':
    #calc_features()
    train_test_separation()
```

But during the training I see something unusual. I see my dataset is not getting trained.
I only changed softmax classifier layer and freezed all other layer above that. When displaying my model summary after that, I recieved a user waring as shown in the heading.

```
_________________________________________________________________
block5_conv1 (Conv2D)        (None, 14, 14, 512)       2359808   
_________________________________________________________________
block5_conv2 (Conv2D)        (None, 14, 14, 512)       2359808   
_________________________________________________________________
block5_conv3 (Conv2D)        (None, 14, 14, 512)       2359808   
_________________________________________________________________
block5_pool (MaxPooling2D)   (None, 7, 7, 512)         0         
_________________________________________________________________
flatten (Flatten)            (None, 25088)             0         
_________________________________________________________________
fc1 (Dense)                  (None, 4096)              102764544 
_________________________________________________________________
fc2 (Dense)                  (None, 4096)              16781312  
_________________________________________________________________
output (Dense)               (None, 2)                 8194      
=================================================================

Warning (from warnings module):
  File "C:\Research\Python_installation\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 973
    'Discrepancy between trainable weights and collected trainable'
UserWarning: Discrepancy between trainable weights and collected trainable weights, did you set `model.trainable` without calling `model.compile` after ?
Total params: 268,529,282
Trainable params: 134,268,738
Non-trainable params: 134,260,544
_________________________________________________________________
Train on 1107 samples, validate on 277 samples
Epoch 1/1

  50/1107 [>.............................] - ETA: 31:43 - loss: 0.7271 - acc: 0.6800������������������������������������������������������������������������������������
 100/1107 [=>............................] - ETA: 28:14 - loss: 5.3602 - acc: 0.5300������������������������������������������������������������������������������������
 150/1107 [===>..........................] - ETA: 26:16 - loss: 7.7642 - acc: 0.4267������������������������������������������������������������������������������������
 200/1107 [====>.........................] - ETA: 24:44 - loss: 8.8050 - acc: 0.3850������������������������������������������������������������������������������������
 250/1107 [=====>........................] - ETA: 23:21 - loss: 9.1716 - acc: 0.3760������������������������������������������������������������������������������������
 300/1107 [=======>......................] - ETA: 22:06 - loss: 9.8458 - acc: 0.3433������������������������������������������������������������������������������������
 350/1107 [========>.....................] - ETA: 20:37 - loss: 10.2353 - acc: 0.3257�������������������������������������������������������������������������������������
 400/1107 [=========>....................] - ETA: 19:04 - loss: 10.4468 - acc: 0.3175�������������������������������������������������������������������������������������
 450/1107 [===========>..................] - ETA: 17:38 - loss: 10.6829 - acc: 0.3067�������������������������������������������������������������������������������������
 500/1107 [============>.................] - ETA: 16:12 - loss: 10.7429 - acc: 0.3060������������������������������������������
```

If the model works fine then the

```
Non-trainable params: 134,260,544
```

count should not be 134,260,544, but 8194. But I got it as 134,260,544 instead of 8194 with the user warning.

When displayed, the predict output of my validated dataset, it was like below.

```
[[0. 1.]
 [0. 1.]
 [0. 1.]
 [0. 1.]
 [0. 1.]
 [0. 1.]
 [0. 1.]
 [0. 1.]
 [0. 1.]
 [0. 1.]
 [0. 1.]
 [0. 1.]
 [0. 1.]
 [0. 1.]
 [0. 1.]
 [0. 1.]
 [0. 1.]
 [0. 1.]
 [0. 1.]
 [0. 1.]
 [0. 1.]
```

This means the data set has not classified correctly at all.

Can someone please help me to identify the fault that I have made.

The user warning I recieved

```
Warning (from warnings module):
  File "C:\Research\Python_installation\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 973
    'Discrepancy between trainable weights and collected trainable'
UserWarning: Discrepancy between trainable weights and collected trainable weights, did you set `model.trainable` without calling `model.compile` after ?
```

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The error message says

> did you set `model.trainable` without calling `model.compile` after ?

In your "vgg16_model" you compile your model first and then start changing the trainable flag of the contained layers. To begin with, you should compile your model after the trainability-changes instead of before and see whether this will resolve your issues.

Comment: KiraMichiru: Million thanks for showing the mistake that I have done. Thanks alot :) <3

Comment: KiraMichiru: your answer makes sense according to the warning. But in case of GANs, if I  initially compile the Discriminator model and then set the `discriminator.trainable=False` and create a combined Generator+Discriminator model, I still get this warning. I can ignore this warning, right ? Because I think the computational graph of my models is correct.